# Getting a minute interval between start and end time mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Id    |    starttime        |    endtime          |
 1    |    1999-05-07 15:00 |    1999-05-07 16:45 |
```

How do I get it interval of 1 minute from the start time to the end time.

So I want something like this `15:01`, `15:02`.

Please any help will be appreciated new to sql and trying to learn it as best I can. Thanks

**NOTE :**

I don't want the whole minute. I want to get every minute from start to end I need it to count the users that logged in every minute of the game if that makes any sense

Comment: Hey @okechukwu anya, to make this question clear please add some expected result. You want 105 rows or 105 values in single column or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,starttime,endtime) FROM Table1
```

**Create this function**

```
CREATE function getTimeAll(id1 int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(65535) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE time1 varchar(65535);
  DECLARE intrvlMin int;
  DECLARE c int;
  SET intrvlMin=(SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,starttime,endtime) FROM Table1 WHERE id = id1);
  SET c=1;
  SET time1 = '';
  While c < intrvlMin
  do
    SET time1=CONCAT(time1,(SELECT date_format(date_add(starttime,interval c minute),'%H:%i') FROM Table1 WHERE id = id1),',');
    SET c = c + 1;
  end WHILE;
  SET time1=CONCAT(time1,(SELECT date_format(date_add(starttime,interval c minute),'%H:%i') FROM Table1 WHERE id = id1));
  RETURN time1;
END ;
```

**Then Run**

```
SELECT `Id`, `starttime`, `endtime`,getTimeAll(`Id`) AS Times FROM Table1;
```

**output**

```
Id  starttime           endtime             Times
1   1999-05-07 15:00:00 1999-05-07 16:45:00 15:01,15:02,15:03,15:04,15:05,15:06,15:07,15:08,15:09,15:10,15:11,15:12,15:13,15:14,15:15,15:16,15:17,15:18,15:19,15:20,15:21,15:22,15:23,15:24,15:25,15:26,15:27,15:28,15:29,15:30,15:31,15:32,15:33,15:34,15:35,15:36,15:37,15:38,15:39,15:40,15:41,15:42,15:43,15:44,15:45,15:46,15:47,15:48,15:49,15:50,15:51,15:52,15:53,15:54,15:55,15:56,15:57,15:58,15:59,16:00,16:01,16:02,16:03,16:04,16:05,16:06,16:07,16:08,16:09,16:10,16:11,16:12,16:13,16:14,16:15,16:16,16:17,16:18,16:19,16:20,16:21,16:22,16:23,16:24,16:25,16:26,16:27,16:28,16:29,16:30,16:31,16:32,16:33,16:34,16:35,16:36,16:37,16:38,16:39,16:40,16:41,16:42,16:43,16:44,16:45
```

**DEMO**

> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nge35TSTWyd3pLSw6X1TE4/2

Comment: This is not what OP wants `So I want something like this 15.01,15.02.`

Comment: So I want to get the interval of 1from the starttime to the endtime. Yes like 15:01 and so on. 15:00 and 16:45 is the duration of the whole game

Comment: So I don't want the whole minute. I want to get every minute from start to end I need it to count the users that logged in every minute of the game if that makes any sense

Comment: Please [edit] your original post to make that clear, then. Readers should not have to pick through comments on other posts to figure out what you really want.

Comment: Check my answer now @okechukwuanya

Comment: hi this is the expected result i want but is there any simple way to do this  without declare function am using mysql

Comment: No because mysql not support while loop out of function and procedure

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use loop ,

Firstly

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,starttime,endtime)  from table1
```

Here you will get 105

This calculates number of minutes between 2 times

```
SELECT date_format(date_add(starttime,interval 1 minute),'%H:%i') from table1
SELECT date_format(date_add(starttime,interval 2 minute),'%H:%i') from table1
SELECT date_format(date_add(starttime,interval 3 minute),'%H:%i') from table1
```

loop this till 105 times with increment interval time